# How to enter symbols and align equations

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

1)I wrote an equation and when I hover my mouse over it it shows perfectly as I want it to but when I am knitting to pdf I get the error 1 :

[image]

Code used for error1:

[image]

```
 $var(u_{t}) = {\delta}_{u}^2 < \infty $
```

This is the whole code for that particular bit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nip1T.png)

2)I have three equations which I want to center and align one underneath the other. When I knit to pdf i get the error 2:

[image]

Code used for error 2:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
$z_{t} & = [(w_{t}/10)^{0.2}]e^t$ \\
$ln(z_{t}) & = 0.2ln(w_{t}/10) + ln(e_{t})$ \\
$y_t & = -0.2ln(10) + 0.2x_{t} + u_{t}$
\end{align*}
```

I also tried to write {latex} in the chunk to fix the issue

I also already loaded packages tidyverse and tinytex.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! First error seems to work fine in my machine. Please check out (how to make reproducible example). Try posting the entire code here. Delete the parts that don't matter. Just keep the important lines that caused the error. This is so we can try to reproduce the error in our own machines as well.

Answer (score 0):

the `align` environment is already a math mode environment so no need to use $-symbols.

```
\begin{align*}
z_{t} & = [(w_{t}/10)^{0.2}]e^t\\
ln(z_{t}) & = 0.2ln(w_{t}/10) + ln(e_{t}) \\
y_t & = -0.2ln(10) + 0.2x_{t} + u_{t}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I didn't use any $ sign for that bit of code and for the first error above I edited my post to include a screenshot of the whole code I used

Comment: screenshots are not recommended. copy paste is preferred for easier access.